# KineticJS get shape object under the mouse position

Tags: javascript, events, webgl, kineticjs

I'm trying to write a little game using KineticJS. The cursor is a gun sight, and I want to use some keyboard keys as the triggers to fire different "bullets" for different effects, but I didn't find a way to do it using JS events.

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage
  container: 'container'
  width: window.innerWidth
  height: window.innerHeight

shape_layer = new Kinetic.Layer()

circle = new Kinetic.Circle
  x: stage.getWidth() / 2
  y: stage.getHeight() / 2
  radius: 100
  fill: 'red'
  stroke: 'white'
  strokeWidth: 20

circle.on 'click', (e) ->
  console.log 'You get one point!'

shape_layer.add circle
stage.add shape_layer

$(document).on 'keydown', (e) ->
  if e.keyCode == 90
    mouse_p = stage.getMousePosition()
    x = mouse_p.x
    y = mouse_p.y
    evt = document.createEvent 'MouseEvents'
    evt.initMouseEvent 'mouseup'
    , true
    , true
    , window
    , null
    , 0
    , 0
    , x
    , y
    shape_layer.fire 'click', evt, true
```

The event is actually fired, but it's on the layer, not the circle. So I start to think is it possible to get the shape using the mouse position and directly fire a click event on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not handle mouse events through KineticJS instead?

```
layer.on('click', function(evt) {
  // get the shape that was clicked on
  var shape = evt.targetNode;
  alert('you clicked on \"' + shape.getName() + '\"');
});
```

Event Delegation: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-get-event-shape-with-kineticjs/

Events: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

**UPDATE:**

I misunderstood your question so my apologies.

You were looking to access the `targetNode` when pressing a key (keydown event). Here's how I would do it:

First you need to set a **transparent rectangle background** with the width and height of the stage, so that the layer can detect mouse events (in this case we need `mousemove`).

```
    var bg = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: stage.getWidth(),
        height: stage.getHeight(),
        id: 'bg'
    });
```

Then, I set an empty `Kinetic.Shape` for whenever the mouse is moving inside the stage but isn't on a target. So, `target` is always equal to `empty` unless mouse is over a node other than our *transparent background*. `scoreText` simply prints your score on the stage.

```
    var empty = new Kinetic.Shape({
        id: 'empty'
    });
    var target = empty;
    var score = 0;

    var scoreText = new Kinetic.Text({
        text: 'Score: '+score,
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        fill: '#000',
        fontSize: 20,
        id: 'score'
    });
```

Use the `mousemove` event in KineticJS:

```
    layer.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
        var x = mousePos.x;
        var y = mousePos.y;
        var node = e.targetNode;
        var nodeID = node.getId();
        if (nodeID !== 'bg') {
            target = node;
        } else {
            target = empty;
        }
    });
```

Then use the jQuery `keydown` event:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 90) {
            var id = target.getId();
            if (id == 'empty' || id == 'score') {
                alert('MISS');
            } else {
                var targetID = target.getId();
                var targetName = target.getName();
                alert('ID: ' + targetID + ' NAME: ' + targetName + ' You get one point!');
                target.destroy();
                target = empty;
                score++;
                updateScore(scoreText, score);
                randomCircle();
            }
        }
    });
```

And finally, for the sake of making a game.. the `randomCircle()` and `updateScore()` functions:

```
    function updateScore(text, score) {
        text.setText('Score: ' + score);
        //layer.draw(); //normally we would have to layer.draw() here, but I called it in randomCircle() instead to save the amount of draw() calls necessary
    }

    function randomCircle() {
        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 578)),
            y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 200)),
            radius: 70,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            id: 'someTarget',
            name: 'targets'
        });
        layer.add(circle);
        layer.draw();
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/yhPhm/) (Don't forget to click on the javascript pane to be able to use the keydown event!)

Comment: Yes, the layer responds now. But it seems the KineticJS engine didn't catch this event and add the targetNode property.

Comment: It should work, exactly like the example in the tutorial does. Are you still using the keydown function on your document? If so I would suggest removing that and moving the function inside KineticJS

Comment: Not clear about your suggestion. My intention was manually and actively fire an event outside the KineticJS, so there should be an keydown function, and compose a mouse event from scratch. The tutorial is not doing the same thing. It just listen to click event on the layer, and wait for user to click.

Comment: Sorry I read your question wrong. Updated my answer above + jsfiddle. Let me know if that solves your question or if you have any questions.